# how to use apple font family in Ubuntu

Tags: css, angular, fonts, font-face

I have tried adding "SanFranciscoFont-master" file

```
   @font-face {
  font-family: "San Francisco";
  src: url("path to folder");
}
```

https://gist.github.com/AndrewBarba/2c0f6612ceef30f5f55d
https://github.com/AppleDesignResources/SanFranciscoFont

still i am not getting the required font

```
font-family: .SFNSDisplay;
```

I have added in asset folder .otf format fonts.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the font
2. Copy it to `/assets/fonts`;
3. Copy this in styles.css:

> @font-face {
>       font-family: 'San Francisco';
>       src: url('/assets/fonts/SanFrancisco.otf');   }

4. Use it : `font-family: "San Francisco";`